# Не работает LOAD DATA INFILE в open server

Tags: сервер

LOAD DATA INFILE
В денвере все прекрасно работает, перешел на Open Server и стали выскакивать ошибки.
В начале были ошибки в связи с local-infile, в конфиге изменил на 1
Потом изменил secure-file-priv  на пустое значение
теперь вылазит ошибка:

error 1300 invalid utf8 character string ''

Перелопатил весь интернет, и англ тоже, кто знает в чем проблема помогите

Comment: Работаю через CMD, запрос LOAD DATA INFILE 'G:/SCCM.csv' INTO TABLE vigruzka FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 ROWS;

Comment: В первых же ссылках по лопачению вылезает: https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/46177-load-data-local-infile-failed-with-error-invalid-utf8-character-string

Comment: Значит надо использовать предыдущую версию сервера?